# a:hover style sticking on iOS browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, oop

I recently released my first open-source project called Shutter Image Gallery and when I was checking to see how it looked on mobile devices (iOS) and noticed a problem that I cannot seem to fix...

[image]

As you can see in the image, the a:hover state on the control buttons seem to stick. The color from a does not return unless you click the opposite button. I tried to search the problem on but couldn't find anything relevant.

The code is open-source and hosted on GitHub. If you can help please do so. Either post the fix here or push it to the repository. I would be extremely grateful.

Link to repository: https://github.com/W3Geek/Shutter

Link to demo: http://w3geek.github.com/Shutter/

Comment: does this happen in all browsers or just on iOS?

Comment: @DanielA.White It works perfectly on desktop browsers. This bug is just on iOS devices as I know of. I cannot check Android devices.

Comment: Sidenote: It's kind of confusing that the new title is shown while still seeing the old picture. It should probably be replaced by a "loading" placeholder right when clicking the link. (and consider preloading the previous/next picture while viewing one)

Comment: @ThiefMaster I know, on the next update on Shutter Image Galley there will be preloading code. I found that earlier and added it to the logs.

Comment: this is just how ios implements hover. its not a bug.

Comment: @DanielA.White Oh?... How would you return the a element back to its original color after it has been clicked? I tried a:visited and a:active but none returned them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a media query in the CSS to only use the a:hover effect on desktops, and instead use an a:active for the color change on iOS devices.

Comment: If media queries could detect iOS devices, sure, that’d work great.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width:650px) 
{
    a:hover 
    {
        color:red;
    }
}

/* Mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width:650px)
{
    a:active
    {
        color:red;
    }
}
```